# Pagination is not working in linux os

Tags: javascript, jsp, pagination

Below is my code,

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title" inline="center"><b>PRODUCT DETAILS</b></div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped col-lg-3">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="#f7d4f7">
              <th>SL No.</td>
              <th>Product Id </th>
              <th>Image Id</th>
              <th>Product Name</th>
              <th>Merchant Name</th>
              <th>price</th>
              <th>Status</th>  
              <th>desc</th>
            </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <%
            for( int index=0; index< productDetails.length; index++)
            {                   
                String productIdColumn = productDetails[ index][ 0];
                String imageIdColumn = productDetails[ index][ 1];
                String productName = productDetails[ index][2];
                String merchantname = productDetails[ index][3];
                String price = productDetails[ index][ 4];
                String status = productDetails[ index][5];
                String desc = productDetails[ index][6];
                if( productIdColumn == null) break;
                %>          
                <tr>                                
                    <td><%= (index+1)%></td>
                    <td><%= imageIdColumn%></td>
                    <td><%= productIdColumn%></td>
                    <td><%= productName%></td>
                    <td><%= merchantname%></td>
                    <td><%= price%></td>
                    <td><%= status%></td>
                    <td><%= desc%></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this image I am getting the same pagination for centos, window7, 8 and 8.1 OS now but not getting for linux.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what's `not working`? Are you getting any errors in your java / browser console? If so post the stacktrace of error too.